# as.h2o is creating 3 levels in my target variable instead of 2 levels so it makes the model multinational instead of binomial, how do I prevent this?

Tags: r, h2o

So I am using h2o.ai to create a binomial classification model however when I use
as.h2o to convert my data sets. It takes my target variable's column header which is "BUY"
and adds that to the levels so instead of just 2 levels 1 and 2 it becomes three levels which are
BUY, 1, and 2. This makes it multinomial and not wanted how do i fix this?

```
when I run perfH2o this is the output:

H2OMultinomialMetrics: gbm

Test Set Metrics: 
=====================

MSE: (Extract with `h2o.mse`) 0.3260208
RMSE: (Extract with `h2o.rmse`) 0.5709823
Logloss: (Extract with `h2o.logloss`) 1.016186
 Mean Per-Class Error: 0.2755556
 R^2: (Extract with `h2o.r2`) -0.1913934
Confusion Matrix: Extract with `h2o.confusionMatrix(<model>, <data>)`)
=========================================================================
Confusion Matrix: Row labels: Actual class; Column labels: Predicted class
   BUY NO YES  Error      Rate
BUY      1  0   0 0.0000 =   0 / 1    #see here it is taking the header and thinking it is a level
NO       0 16   9 0.3600 =  9 / 25
YES      0  7   8 0.4667 =  7 / 15
Totals   1 23  17 0.3902 = 16 / 41

Hit Ratio Table: Extract with `h2o.hit_ratio_table(<model>, <data>)`
=======================================================================
Top-3 Hit Ratios: 
 k hit_ratio
1 1  0.609756
2 2  0.975610
3 3  1.000000
```

Here is my code

```
#Getting packages
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
#install.packages("tidyquant") #Used to quickly load the "tidyverse" (dplyr, tidyr, ggplot, etc) 
along with custom, 
#business-report-friendly ggplot themes. Also great for time series analysis (not featured)
library(tidyquant)
#install.packages("unbalanced")
library(unbalanced)#contains various methods for working with unbalanced data. I will be using 
ubSMOTE() function

#installing H20 latest stable release H20 is a professional machine learning package

# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
#if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
#if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
#pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
#for (pkg in pkgs) {
# if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
#}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
#install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yule/2/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

#Now getting the data
ngData <- read.csv(file.choose())

#Now I am going to create my Train, validation, and test set
splitPercentage1 <- .70
splitPercentage2 <- .5
numRows1 <- nrow(ngData)
sampleSize1 <- floor(splitPercentage1*numRows1)

set.seed(1)

idxTrain1 <- sample(1:numRows1, size = sampleSize1)
validationRaw <- ngData[-idxTrain1,]
trainRaw <- ngData[idxTrain1,]
#validation set created now time to make test set out of validation set

numRows2 <- nrow(validationRaw)
sampleSize2 <- floor(splitPercentage2*numRows2)
idxTrain2 <- sample(1:numRows2, size = sampleSize2)
testRaw <- validationRaw[-idxTrain2,]
validationRaw <- validationRaw[idxTrain2,]

#Now I have a randomly set train set, validation set, and test set

View(trainRaw)
View(testRaw)
View(validationRaw)

#all look good however we need our target variable "BUY" to be a factor not numeric
#also Buy = 1 Sell = 0 in the BUY column

trainRaw[,11] <- as.factor(trainRaw[,11])
testRaw[,11] <- as.factor(testRaw[,11])
validationRaw[,11] <- as.factor(validationRaw[,11])

View(trainRaw)
View(testRaw)
View(validationRaw)

#now to balance the data which i don't know if that is very necessary so I 
#will check how balanced it is

Buytable <- table(trainRaw$BUY)
Buydistr <- prop.table(Buytable)
Buydistr

 #very balanced with 52% sell and 47% buy so no need to balance

 h2o.no_progress()

#converting into h2o data frames
trainH20 <- as.h2o(trainRaw)
validH20 <- as.h2o(validationRaw)
testH20 <- as.h2o(testRaw)

#now to find a classification model

y <- "BUY"
x <- setdiff(names(trainH20), y)

automl_models_h2o <- h2o.automl(
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  training_frame    = trainH20,
  validation_frame  = validH20,
  leaderboard_frame = testH20,
  max_runtime_secs  = 60
 )

 #time to extract the leading model

 NGLeader <- automl_models_h2o@leader

 #making predicitons using h2o.predict()

predH2o <- h2o.predict(NGLeader, newdata = testH20)
as_tibble(predH2o)

#now to check the performance
perfH2o <- h2o.performance(NGLeader, newdata = testH20)
perfH2o

 h2o.r2(perfH2o)
 #very bad r^2

  #turns out my model believes that BUY is one of the possible outcomes of Y so it is multinomial I 
 must fix that

 #######################################################################
```

Here is a glimpse() of my data:

Rows: 185

Columns: 11

$ ï..Month  April, July, August, August, July, February, September, January, March, February, June,...

$ East.Region           -12, 24, 26, 21, 19, -43, 25, -43, -15, -9, 27, -28, 26, -27, 22, 23, 32, -54, 21, 12, ...

$ Midwest.Region        -20, 20, 36, 29, 16, -47, 35, -38, -7, -4, 35, -31, 45, -27, 22, 29, 27, -56, 30, 14, -...

$ Mountain.Region       -4, 6, 4, 3, 2, -6, 3, -10, 2, 0, 9, -2, 5, -9, 5, 3, 6, -6, 4, 2, -4, 5, 5, 3, -1, -7,...

$ Pacific.Region        5, 5, 2, 0, -1, -10, 5, -13, 9, -1, 11, -3, 0, -14, 7, 0, 9, -11, 0, -3, -8, 5, 5, 6, 0...

$ South.Central.Region  12, 3, 2, -2, -2, -41, 37, -15, 35, 21, 18, 1, 20, -10, 5, -6, 32, -38, 12, -14, -6, 17...

$ Salt                  8, -5, -2, -5, -6, -19, 14, 13, 19, 5, -1, -1, 3, 15, -5, -3, 12, -8, 1, -13, -3, 3, -2...

$ NonSalt               3, 7, 4, 4, 3, -22, 22, -28, 18, 16, 18, 3, 17, -25, 10, -4, 19, -29, 11, -2, -3, 15, 1...

$ Total.Lower.48        -19, 58, 69, 51, 34, -149, 105, -119, 23, 7, 98, -63, 96, -87, 61, 49, 106, -163, 67, 1...

$ Flow.Change           -0.34, -0.06, 0.41, 3.64, -0.47, -0.10, 0.42, -0.51, -1.64, -1.08, -0.15, -0.27, 0.43, ...

$ BUY                   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first choice (better, but more lines of code have to change) is not to load the data into R, and have H2O [load](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/importing-data.html) it, and also have H2O [split](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/splitting-datasets.html) it instead. The H2O loader will recognize the first row is a header row and treat it as column names, and not as data.

The second approach is to strip out the header row in the R code.

However, that is already the default behaviour of `read.csv()` (the `header` argument defaults to `TRUE`). So your data must have "BUY" somewhere other than the first row. In which case either fix the data manually, or seek and destroy that bad row after loading it into R.

(If you disagree, can you post a sample data file that demonstrates the problem, using the code you have given.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try both out and see how they go. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you post data, it should be enough data to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or the R-specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/841830

Comment: Sorry, my fault I am pretty new to stack overflow I will try to figure it out; however, I removed the header row and it worked so thank you for that solution! Im quite new to R so I am trying to learn all these new things :)

Comment: > I removed the header row and it worked 
That is strange, as the data glimpse showed it had correctly interpreted the header row, and the first real data was a `0`.   Anyway, glad it now works!